# How to pop out the error-causing date records using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['45:42.7','11/1/2012 0:00','20/1/2012 2:48','15/1/2012 0:00',np.nan]})
```

I would like to convert the `date` column to type `datetime`.

So, I tried the below

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

I get the below error

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

As we can see from the sample dataframe `NA` is not causing this error but the 1st record which is `45:42.7`.

While the raw excel file displays this date value `45:42.7` when I open the file but when I double click the cell, it displays correctly the actual date.

How can I filter the dataframe to pop-out the first record as output (which is the error causing record)?

I expect my output to be like shown in sample dataframe below

df = pd.DataFrame({'error_date': ['45:42.7']})

Comment: just pass `errors` parameter and set that equal to `coerce` in `to_datetime()` method i.e `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],errors='coerce')`

Comment: @AnuragDabas - will it not be possible to find those bad records causing errors?

Comment: I think coerce will change them to `NA`

Comment: Yes It changes them to `NaT`

Comment: No, I would like to review what are those bad records that are causing this error

Comment: Then just filtered those values which are NaT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if need to see wrong values convert to datetimes and filter missing values like:

```
print(df[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',errors='coerce').isna()])
```

I think `None` is no problem, you need specify column format and for not matched rows are generated `NaN`s if add `errors='coerce'` parameter:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',errors='coerce')
print (df)
                 date
0 2012-03-06 08:57:00
1 2012-01-11 00:00:00
2 2012-01-20 02:48:00
3 2012-01-15 00:00:00
4                 NaT
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. but wouldn't coerce change those bad records to `NA`. Instead I would like to see what are those bad records

Comment: @TheGreat - Added to answer.

Comment: Hi, for example, in my csv file, some of the dates are like this `45:42.7 ` but when I double click the cell in csv, proper date in displayed. But when pandas reads csv, it reads date value as `45:42.7`. How can I make pandas read the correct date value (which is seen when I double click the cell in csv)?

Comment: @TheGreat - `but when I double click the cell in csv` - You think in excel? Some excel datetimes are wrongly parsed?

Comment: When I double click the cell in Excel, I am able to see the correct date... If I don't double click, I only see dates as `45:42.7`.. So, pandas also reads date as `45:42.7`

Comment: @TheGreat - hmmm, so after read in excel are returned `45:42.7` ? Not some floats?

Comment: Yes, when I use `pd.read_excel` to read the file, it reads the date as is (which is `45:42.7` ) without actual date

Comment: @TheGreat - What is correct format for `45:42.7` ?

Comment: same format as you have mentioned in your code

Comment: @TheGreat - I think what is correct datetime for `45:42.7`

Comment: `10/11/1990 12:45:42 AM`. I think we can leave this. I will update data owners on this to fix in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

The Error is caused by using something like 24:00.
Testing with (note the change in the second entry to 24:00):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['6/3/2012 8:57','11/1/2012 24:00','20/1/2012 2:48','15/1/2012 0:00',np.nan]})
```

We receive the same error as in your big dataframe. Going trough with a for loop maybe a bit slower but this way we can catch the errors.

```
wrong_datetime_list = []
for index, value in enumerate(df['date']):
    try:
        df.loc[index,'date']= pd.to_datetime(df.loc[index,'date'])
    except:
        wrong_datetime_list.append((index, value))
```

Comment: thanks..upvoted...error was caused due to a record like this `45:42.7` in my date column. However, when I double click the cell in raw csv file, am able to see the actual date. But pandas reads date as `45:42.7` but not the actual value.